# paper-dropdown-menu vertical align

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

After upgrading to v0.5.1 vertical align attribute seems to be removed from paper-dropdown-menu,

before I was doing something like this to control the vertical align, but it isn't working any more:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="typeSelector" halign="{{lang == 'ar' ? 'right' : 'left'}}" selected="{{selectedGroupTypeId}}">
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Any way to do something like this with the updated element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now `valign` and `halign` attributes are available on [`paper-dropdown`](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown/demo.html) element, because it extends [`core-dropdown`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html) and `paper-dropdown-menu` doesn't extend it any more.